# R create and populate new columns based on values in another

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm stuck on an R data wrangling issue. I have a data frame (df) that looks like this:

> ```
>       loc     lat      long      group
>  1    loc1    47.69119 -91.85776  A
>  2    loc1    47.69119 -91.85776  B
>  3    loc1    47.69119 -91.85776  C
>  4    loc2    46.41079 -86.64089  C
>  5    loc2    46.41079 -86.64089  C
>  6    loc2    46.41079 -86.64089  C
>  7    loc3    47.33673 -91.19876  D
>  8    loc4    46.83937 -87.71222  A
>  9    loc4    46.83937 -87.71222  E
>  10   loc4    46.83937 -87.71222  E
> ```

What I would like to do is create a new column for each unique value in df$group, then use the number of times each group is observed for each loc to populate the new columns, and retain only a single row for each loc. I would like the final product to look like this:

> ```
>       loc    lat      long       A  B  C  D  E
>  1    loc1   47.69119 -91.85776  1  1  1  0  0
>  2    loc2   46.41079 -86.64089  0  0  3  0  0
>  3    loc3   47.33673 -91.19876  0  0  0  1  0
>  4    loc4   46.83937 -87.71222  1  0  0  0  2
> ```

I think I need some combination of dplyr and/or tidyr functions, but haven't been able to work it out. I've tabulated the frequency for each loc and group using the following code:

```
df.freq = df %>%
group_by(loc, group) %>%
summarise(Freq = n())
```

Perhaps the resulting df.freq can be used to create the new columns using tidyr as follows:

```
tidyr::separate(df.freq, group, 
  as.character(unique(df.freq$group)))
```

But then I'm not sure how to populate each new column and retain only a single row for each loc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to get the `count` based on the columns 'loc', 'lat', 'long', 'group' and then `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  count(loc, lat, long, group) %>%
  spread(group, n, fill = 0)
```

---

A `data.table` version (@markus comments) would be

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), loc + lat + long ~ group)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @akrun, works perfectly and with little code!

Comment: Thanks also @markus, another simple solution that works well.

Comment: it can be simplified further for `tidyverse`:

`df %>% dcast(loc + lat + long ~ group)`